# Speed up C++ code performance (map, find(), input and output)

Tags: c++, dictionary, find, stdmap

We input into console sequence of `pairs(a,b)` of `int` values. Then we input sequence of integers(`z`). And if we have some `a[i] == z`, should output `b[i]`.

```cpp
    int main()
    {
        std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);

        std::map<int, int> mp;
        std::map<int, int>::iterator iter;

        int x, y;
        while (std::cin >> x && x != -1 && std::cin >> y && y != -1) {
            mp[x] = y;
        }
        while (std::cin >> x && x != -1) {
            iter = mp.find(x);
            if (iter != mp.end())
                std::cout << iter->second << ' ';
            else
                std::cout << 0 << ' ';
        }
        std::cout << -1;
    }
```

Code not fast enough, please help me to understand what I need to do to make it faster.

---

SOLUTION: Actually, trouble was in "mp.find(x)". Need just "mp[x]" ...

Comment: I think as well, but I could be wrong. But "they" tell me that it is not fast enough for our tasks. Let's say it is 90 percent fast, and we need 100 all. I can’t understand what else can be done with this without weird things (like inserting an assembler code).

Comment: Use `std::unordered_map` instead of `std::map`.

Comment: I have to come up with a hash function faster than searching in the standard case, I suppose. I have no idea how to do this with such simplicity of the task.

Comment: Step 1: make sure you build your code with compiler optimizations *enabled* (the default in most cases is "optimizations disabled" to give a better debugging experience). Your IDE may call it "Debug build" vs "Release build". In some cases the difference can be orders of magnitude, performance wise. Step 2: Profile it.

Comment: Usually, *not fast enough* or Time Limit Exceeded (TLE) errors are a result from choosing a slow algorithm.  See if you can change your design to use a faster algorithm, or use more math, or simplify.  Rarely, do these online challenges require coding optimizations.

Comment: The problem with search times is that the search depends on the quantity of data and whether it is sorted or not.  For small sets of data, a linear search may be faster than a map.  If the data range is small, you could use a fixed array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing in your code that indicates you need a sorted map.  So, use an `std::unordered_map`, which is usually much faster than `std::map`.

---

Also note that some of those who think `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false);` matters add something like this to it :

```
std::cin.tie(nullptr);
std::cout.tie(nullptr);
```